# javascript/jquery event issues with mouseup and mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

```
var vol_drag = false;
$('.video-volume-wrapper').on('mousedown', 'div', function(e){
  vol_drag = true;
  update_volume(e.pageX)
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
  if(vol_drag === true){
    update_volume(e.pageX);
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
  if(vol_drag === true){
    vol_drag = false;
    update_volume(e.pageX);
  }
});


function update_volume(x){
  var bar = $('.video-bar-inner-wrapper');
  var max_vol = max_vol_pos;
  var position = x - vol_bar_start_pos;
  var curr_vol = parseFloat((position-0)/(max_vol-0));

  if(curr_vol > 1){
    curr_vol = 1;
  }

  if(curr_vol < 0){
    curr_vol = 0;
  }

  $('.volume-position').css({'left':(curr_vol*100)+'%'});
  $('.video-volume-bar').css('width',(curr_vol*100)+'%');
  video.volume = curr_vol;
};
```

I have this code that allows me to control the volume of an HTML 5 video element, but sometimes after I drag the volume slider and release the mouse button (mouseup event) the mousemove still gets activated causing an effect which has the slider stuck under the cursor even though the mouseup should set vol_drag variable to false and should stop the mousemove event from happening. Anybody with this experience and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: you might wanna try `[videojs lib]`(http://videojs.com/) instead of directly using video tag
It will help you with all events and it is easy to use

Comment: This situation will happen if the mouse leaves the document frame. Try to solve this by checking document mouse out event.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy i added the mouseout check it solves that problem but creates a new one, the slider no longer works properly as mouseout is constantly setting vol_drag to false it seems

Comment: You can try to ignore my previous solution and change the document to window. I am not sure either so please see if it works

Comment: Hi, Could you please try to create fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: @Samundra sorry for late reply, here is the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/miccetro/abcunzd2/2/) play with the volume slider and you'll see it gets stuck under the mouse at times.

Comment: I tried few times but didn't face the issue. Maybe it's specific to browser. I tested with Chrome.

Comment: @Samundra there was some unnecessary js in that fiddle so here is a clean up (https://jsfiddle.net/miccetro/abcunzd2/5/) click and drag it back and forward then release the mouse button.